# Can I extract the IP/Port of the client from a WebSocketConnection instance?

Tags: dart

Is there any way whereby given a `WebSocketConnection` instance I can extract the IP/port of the client it represents? I know that the implementation (namely `_WebSocketConnectionBase`) has a `Socket` as a private variable, but I cannot hack it. Is there any workaround?

The environment in which I need this functionality is this: I have a server that handles web socket connections, and I would like to store the IP of the client alongside their web socket. I instantiate my server like so:

```
var server = new HttpServer();
var wsHandler = new WebSocketHandler();

wsHandler.onOpen = this.subscribeUser;
server.addRequestHandler((req) => req.path == "/ws", wsHandler.onRequest);
...
subscribeUser(WebSocketConnection user){...}
```

Is it possible to hack in this functionality somewhere in this code maybe? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If the `socket` variable is private and you have no other way to access it (and need to), I would consider filing a bug.  But I'm not sure there isn't another way to to get the information you want.

Comment: Yes, please do file a bug. This should be possible without resorting to hacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try make an extended implementation of WebSocketHandler and get the request from here. An example:

```dart
class betterWebSocket implements WebSocketHandler {
  WebSocketHandler _wsHandler = new WebSocketHandler();

  void onRequest(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) {
    print(request.connectionInfo.remoteHost); // Print the IP of the remote to the screen
    _wsHandler.onRequest(request, response);
  }

  void set onOpen(callback(WebSocketConnection connection)) {
    _wsHandler.onOpen = callback;
  }
}
```

You can use this class as an normal WebSocketHandler:

```dart
void main() {
  HttpServer server = new HttpServer();
  betterWebSocket wsHandler = new betterWebSocket();

  server.addRequestHandler((req) => req.path == "/", wsHandler.onRequest);

  wsHandler.onOpen = (WebSocketConnection conn) {
    print("New connection");

    conn.onMessage = (message) {
      print("message is $message");
    };

    conn.onClosed = (int status, String reason) {
      print('closed with $status for $reason');
    };

  server.listen('127.0.0.1', 20024);
};
```